# 4 queen, min conflicts

Tags: conflict, min, n-queens

I would like some help with [min-conflicts algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-conflicts_algorithm).

```
  A B C D
1 _ _ Q Q
2 Q _ _ _
3 _ _ _ _
4 _ Q _ _
```

If we are at this point,

- will the algorithm choose **randomly** to move either `C` or `D` because both of them create the same number of conflicts (`C` in conflict with `D`, `D` in conflict with `C`),
- **or** will it choose `D` because the best place we can move `C` is in 3rd row and that will result in 1 conflict and if we choose `D` and move it in 3rd row will result in 0 conflicts.

Comment: Which "the algorithm" are we talking about here?

Comment: Min-conflicts algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant lines from the wikipedia page:

```
 var <-- a randomly chosen variable from the set of conflicted variables CONFLICTED[csp]
 value <-- the value v for var that minimizes CONFLICTS(var,v,current,csp)
 set var = value in current_state
```

1. `var` represents the position of queen C or D, chosen at random.
2. Set `var` to the position for said queen that minimizes conflicts given the rest of the board

So, it's your first choice, "the algoryth choose randomly to move either C or D...", but not "because both of them create the same number of conflicts." Either C or D because those participate in one or more conflicts.

It does mention "If there is more than one value with *a minimum number of conflicts*, it chooses one randomly."  Once you understand the basic formulation of the algorithm, it seems there may be this modification which may also be considered a min-constraints search.